# Huge lag with linux Traffic Control - TBF failed?

Tags: networking

I've been working with Ubuntu18.04 and trying to shape the traffic with linux tc. Things went well in the passed few months. Here's my commands:

```
# init queue
sudo tc qdisc add dev enp2s0 root handle 1:0 tbf rate 20mbit limit 16k burst 10k
sudo tc qdisc add dev enp2s0 parent 1:0 handle 10: netem rate 20mbit

# continuously adjust the traffic using following command with python
sudo tc qdisc add dev enp2s0 parent 1:0 handle 10: netem rate <bandwidth>kbit delay <rtt>ms loss <loss>%
```

However recent days ****I noticed that TBF seemed to stop working.****

### How do I know that

I used iperf3 to test the link:

```
# receiver, a windows pc
iperf3 -s

# sender, a linux PC performing tc & iperf client
iperf3 -u -c <receiver's ip> -b 1.5M -t 1000
```

The bandwidth was set to vary around **1M bps**.

1. I observed a **huge lag** between the fluctuation of bandwidth set on the sender and throughput observed on the receiver.
2. After the sender exited, the receiver **could still receive remaining packets in a few seconds**. (sum up to around 5~10 Mbit)
3. Things went on normally when I tried to iperf with **TCP**: `iperf3 -c <receiver's ip> -b 1.5M -t 1000`. I think it was because TCP had a scheme to perf the bandwidth and would not produce excessive packets. And it's why I think it was TBF that failed instead of other components.

I've tried

1. replacing the network card
2. changing iperf client
3. replacing the cable

None of the above helped.